# call \pygment with `#` or `%` character in tabularx environment

Tags: tabularx, pythontex

I have the following MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
\pygment{c}{#include <stdio.h>} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

which give me

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \pytx@argdetok.
Illegal parameter number in definition of \pytx@arg.
Illegal parameter number in definition of \pytx@argdetok.
Illegal parameter number in definition of \pytx@arg.
Illegal parameter number in definition of \pytx@argdetok.
Illegal parameter number in definition of \pytx@arg.
```

I studied a bit the behavior of `\pygment{c}{#include <stdio.h>}` :

1. This line works outside `tabularx` environment
2. If I remove `#` in `#include`, the error goes away.

Side notes :

1. Compilation :
   `pdflatex main.tex && pythontex main.tex && pdflatex main.tex`
2. It seems to be a known issue, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116660/125774) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83573/125774) of G. Poore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can locally make `#` safe:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

{\catcode`\#=12
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
\pygment{c}{#include <stdio.h>} \\
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! [G. Poore said that it wouldn't be hard to get around it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83558/error-caused-by-interaction-between-minted-footnotes-babel-and-double-quote/83573#83573) but I did not have enough TeX knowledge. Just a bit curious, in your opinion why this solution cannot be implemented in the package?

Comment: @FirminMartin the solution is document specific,  you need to move the making `#` safe up so it is not in the argument of any command (normally environments are Ok but tabularx is "special") but not so early that it comes before and definitions like `\newcomand\foo[1]{zzz  #1}` which need the special `#` behaviour. so in your example, it can not be done when pythontex is loaded (as that would break `\usepackage{tabularx}`) and it can not be done by the `\pygment` command as that is already inside `tabularx` so it is too late to change `#`